# Nextjs routing: both a directory and a .tsx

Tags: next.js

What does it mean to nextjs routing when you have:

regular file: ./pages/pipelines/[pipelineId].tsx

directory: ./pages/pipelines/[pipelineId]

What is the meaning of having both in the same project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach with the slug inside the directory name opens up possibilities for more complex routing scenarios. Inside this directory, you can have additional files or subdirectories that represent nested routes.

For instance, if you have a file named `edit.tsx` inside this directory, it would be accessible via a URL like /pipelines/123/edit.

Comment: You appear to be saying that ./pages/pipelines/[pipelineId].tsx is terminal, while ./pages/pipelines/[pipelineId] can be part of a longer slug?